# How to change widget's size without pushing others

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

The **"ok"** button separates the two entry boxes from each other. I want them to stick together and the button making a square at the end of the two entries:

*Here's the code*

```
ventana = Tk()
ventana.geometry("500x300")


pathLabel = Label(ventana, text="Path of file: ").grid(row=0)
nameLabel = Label(text="Name of file").grid(row=1)

ePath = Entry()
eName = Entry()

ePath.grid(row=0, column=1)
eName.grid(row=1, column=1)

Ok = Button(text="okay", command=savepath)
Ok.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=N)
Ok.configure(height=5)

ventana.mainloop()
```

*This is how it looks*

[image]

*I want it to look like this*

[image: this]

Thanks.

Comment: Either use a `Frame` around the `Label`or use [`rowspan=`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid-method)

Comment: @stovfl: using a frame in and of itself does nothing here, I think that recommendation will only serve to confuse the OP.

Comment: @BryanOakley ***serve to confuse***: See the working [LIve-Demo](https://repl.it/repls/FearlessSpectacularBrowser#main.py) using `Frame`

Comment: @stovfl: I'll stand by my assertion. Without giving actual details, saying "Use a Frame" isn't useful. You say to put it around "the label", but your demo puts it around both the labels and the entry widgets.  Putting a frame around a label or both labels alone won't solve the problem and just adds confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is for the button to be on row zero and extend to row one. So, that's exactly what you should tell grid.

If you want the button to exactly fit those two rows, I recommend *not* giving the button an explicit size. Instead, let `grid` make the button expand to fill the two rows by using the `sticky` option.

```
Ok.grid(row=0, column=2, rowspan=2, sticky="nsew")
```